# Mason's Gain Formula with a not connected loops

Tags: gain, formula-derivation

We have the following path.

[image]

I tried to create the gain with Mason's formula, which lead me to the following:

```
Forward Path 1: 1
Loop 1: (1/s)*(2/s)*2
Loop 2: (-1)*(2/s)*2
```

When I put them together I get:

```
(1/1 - ((1/s)*(2/s)*2) - ((2/s)*2)) * (-1)*(2/s)*2
```

If I multiply it with `s^2` I get

```
(-4s)/(s^2+4s+4)
```

But according to the solution it should be

```
(s^2 + 4s)/(s^2+4s+4)
```

So my upper part does not match. Do I use Mason's Gain Formula wrong?

Comment: Can you offer a better picture that more easily distinguishes between the characters 2,Z and S.

Comment: I added a better one.

Comment: Isn't loop 1 (1/s)*(2/s)*2? You seem to be using 1/2 instead of 1/s.

Comment: ah sorry, I typed it wrong

Comment: So was that your error?

Comment: No on the paper I solved it, I wrote it right. But I made a mistake when I typed it into stackexchange :)